# How to remove directories that have numbers as file names using command line?

Tags: bash, shell-script, directory

I have a directory where there are subdirectories which have numbers as directories. For example I have a parent directory `test` now I have some subdirectories like `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`,`7`.

Now I have a local exported variable like `export a=3`. I want to delete directories that are above or equal to `$a` but below or equal to `$a+2`, So I want to delete directories `3`, `4`,`5`.

Also if I don't know the least number directory and I want to delete everything below or equal to `$a` so the directories `1`,`2`,`3` gets deleted. How can I achieve this?

I tried `rm -rf {$a..$($a+3)}` and `rm -rf {<$a}`, it didn't work, I tried so many other things but not successful.

Comment: you only have one `$a`, and you do calculating lower and upper both based on the `$a`, so what do mean when you are saying _"`Also if I don't know the least number directory and I want to delete everything below or equal to <$a`"_?

Comment: You tagged bash, but would you be open to a `zsh`-based solution?

Answer (score 5):

You could use zsh instead of bash which has a glob operator to match on range of decimal integer numbers and can also restrict globs to files of a given type (such as *directory* in your case).

The `<3-5>` glob matches on strings that make up numbers 3 to 5, which includes 3, 4 and 5 but also `03`, `003`. The digits have to be literal though. You can still use variables, if you do things like:

```
range="<$a-$((a+2))>"
rm -rf test/$~range(/)
```

Where `$~range` forces the parameter expansion to be taken as a pattern, and `(/)` restricts to files of type *directory*.

You can do without the intermediary variable if you use an anonymous function:

```
() { rm -rf test/$~1(/); } "<$a-$((a+2))>"
```

To match on numbers that are less than 4, just use `<0-3>` or `<-3>`. To also include negative numbers: `(-<->|<0-3>)`.

Your `{$a..$((a+2))}` approach would work in zsh, though that expands to `3`, `4`, `5` regardless of whether files by that name exist or not (and wouldn't match on 03, 00005...). The fact that it doesn't work is a limitation that affects only the bash shell (among the shells that support `{x..y}` which actually is a zsh invention).

Answer (score -2):

Assuming there are only directories with numbers as names then we can use:

```bash
rm -rf $(seq $(ls | head -1) $a)
```